# Setting up custom stemming in solr

Tags: solr

I have been following the tutorial for solr, and am attempting to enable custom stemming, but I can't get it to work.

The first problem I ran into was that I couldn't find the schema.xml file.  Most of the documentation I saw implied that it would be in the following location:

```
/solr-4.9.0/example/solr/
```

but the only one I found was here:

```
/solr-4.9.0/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
```

I modified that file to contain the following:

```
<fieldtype name="plumbing_abbrev" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StemmerOverrideFilterFactory"
            dictionary="stemdict.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

In the same directory as the schema.xml file, I made a file called stemdict.txt which contains insinkerator\tise.

I expect this to make it so I can type in insinkerator and get documents that have the string ise in them, but it isn't working, typing in insinkerator gets none of the ise hits.  What am I doing wrong?

------edit-------

I tried changing stemdict.txt to bogus, and when I started up the solr server, it didn't work, throwing an exception saying that there was no such file as bogus.  This suggests that it is indeed finding, and using, the stemdict.txt file, but it just isn't using it to actually do anything useful.

To help, here is a screen shot of analysis for the field in question:

[image: Screen Shot of the Analysis tab]

Comment: Did you reindex your data after adding the StemmerOverrideFilterFactory to the schema.xml file?

Comment: I deleted all of the data and re-imported it, so I believe the answer to that question is yes.

Comment: ok - did you also restart Solr too?

Comment: Yes I have restarted Solr as well.

Comment: You might want to consider adding a LowerCaseTokenFilter before the stemming filter. PorterStemFilterFactory only works with lowercase letters (from the docs). Additionally, StemmerOverrideFilterFactory has an "ignoreCase" flag you might want to enable.

Comment: When you say "have the string ise in them", do you mean that it has the _word_ ise, or just the substring "ise" present somewhere in a word? Could you add the output from the `analysis` page under Admin for your core for the content of the field and what you are searching?

Comment: @spyk what is a lower case token filter, and how do you add one?  I tried <filter class="solr.LowerCaseTokenFilterFactory"/> and that didn't exist, and I tried looking for LowerCastTokenFilter on google and it turned up nothing that looked relevant.  I did put the ignoreCase="true" on, and will adjust the question accordingly.

Comment: I would like to search for insinkerator and have documents that contain ise or ISE come up, which is not happening.

Comment: do you mean contain the word ISE or ise or something contain ise. If the word "Realise" were in your document would you expect it to match? How about "Risen"?

Comment: Some items in the collection contain a string where "ISE" is a word.  I would like it so that typing in insinkerator will dig up the items that have the word "ISE"

Comment: The analysis looks ok, the documents should match. Did you try re-indexing and then running the query again?

Comment: I deleted all the data from the server, then restarted the server, then re-imported all of the data, and ran the query again and it still does not work, which I believe is equivalent to re-indexing and rerunning the query.

Comment: is your query definitely on the specific field? Can you try running _name:insinkerator_ as the query text?

Comment: name:insinkerator returns the results I was looking for.  How do you make it so you can just type in insinkerator without the name: and it works?

Comment: You have to look into your solrconfig.xml and find the default field. It should be under "/select" request handler, look for the "df" param and change it to: `<str name="df">name</str>`

Comment: I tried that and it fixed the problem with the result not showing up, but it introduced a new problem, which is that you can't look for something by its id any more.  Is there any way to make it so that a query looks for the search term in all fields?

Comment: I figured out what I needed to do in order to get both to work at the same time.  The default value for the df is "text" which is an amalgamation field that contains all of the textual data, but its type was text_general.  I changed that to be plumbing_abbrev, and added the id to that field as well, and it started working correctly.